# how to array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<double> numbers(input_number);

    cout << "Enter numbers from 0 to 50: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < input_number; ++i) {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    unordered_map<int, int> freq;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        freq[numbers[i]]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {

        cout << freq[numbers[i]];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the use inputs numbers, for example 1,1,1,2 the output should be "1" because it is the most frequent number but the output here became "3,3,3,1" How to solve this problem?[image]

Comment: The shown code will not even compile. Can you show real code that was compiled and executed?

Comment: @drescherjm yes that's my problem, The output should print the most frequent number not the frequency. For example if the user input the numbers, 1,2,2,2,3. Th output should be 2.

Answer (score 2):

You are most of the way there.  Your frequencies are all stored, and you just need to search through the `unordered_map` now to find the item that has the largest value.  Since you're already using `<algorithm>` you can leverage `std::max_element` to help:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2 };
    std::unordered_map<int, int> freq;
    for (int n : numbers) ++freq[n];

    if (!freq.empty())
    {
        auto it = std::max_element(freq.begin(), freq.end(),
            [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.second < b.second; });
        std::cout << "Most frequent is " << it->first << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Most frequent is 2
```

Here, a custom comparison function is supplied that tests only the frequency part of the element (otherwise the default behavior will compare the full key/value pairs which will result in finding the largest *number*).

Note that because the map is unordered, there won't be a predictable outcome for tie-breakers (where more than one number is the most frequent).  If you need to handle that in a more predictable way, you'll need to adjust the comparison function or possibly just loop over the container yourself if it requires additional work.

One option for tie-breaking is to choose the lowest number.  That could be achieved by modifying the comparison to:

```
return std::make_pair(a.second, b.first) < std::make_pair(b.second, a.first);
```

Comment: That won't be appropriate, because the map's comparison function is only for its key.  Maybe you can add to your own answer your ideas for what you're talking about here.

Comment: hmm, why I remember iy somehow being done, did `boost` had another type of map or a helper?

Comment: Probably..  Boost has a ton of stuff and you almost have to know it's there before you go looking.  I've recently been playing around with the boost intrusive containers to solve a particular problem that's really inefficient and memory-hungry with standard containers.  Pretty cool stuff.  Doubt it's necessary here.  Even if they want to pull all the frequencies in order, that could be achieved easily by sticking them in a vector and sorting it, or using a priority queue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you just output all the values in map. In a naive implementation you have to iterate through map and register the maximum value and it's frequency:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    using std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;
    using std::vector, std::unordered_map;
    
    int input_number = 0, max_freq = 0, max_val = 0;
    cout << "How many numbers you want to input: " << endl;
    cin >> input_number;
    
    // Making input double may creates questions
    vector<int> numbers(input_number);

    cout << "Enter numbers from 0 to 50: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < input_number; ++i) {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    
    unordered_map<int, int> freq;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        freq[numbers[i]]++;
    }
    
    // iterating over the map and finding max value
    for (auto val : freq) {
        if( val.second > max_freq) {
            max_val = val.first;
            max_freq = val.second;
        }
    }
    cout << max_val;

    return 0;
}
```

Standard maps do store values as pairs of key and value (std::pair). This can be done in easier way: you can do that right while inputting the numbers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
    int val = numbers[i];
    int curfreq = ++freq[val];
    if (curfreq > max_freq) {
        max_val = val;
        max_freq = curfreq;
    }        
}

cout << max_val;
```

Comment: This solution has the nice property that tie-breaking decisions are deterministic based on the order in which values arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Your array freq has to proper values in it. But your logic in the print out is wrong. You are printing the numbers twice. I guess you want to print all the numbers from 0 to 50.

```
cout << freq[i]
```

Then you see which entries have values or not. Then add some logic (which doesn't exist in your code) to pick the proper value. Like the biggest count..

Comment: that would create uninitialized values

Comment: Let's hope he does something meaningful, and not just print all the values. At least he can improve his code, if he sees some zeros, and some numbers on the correct position.

Comment: You have completely misinterpreted what the OP is trying to achieve, and the advice is misleading.  They want the program to output the value that occurs most frequently in the input.  They _don't_ want to look up indices relative to the `numbers` vector and just hope that index corresponds to a value that was counted.  This answer takes them further away from a solution than their original code.